# How to change validation message from string length ASP.NET Core

Tags: string, forms, asp.net-core, validation

I want to validate input in a form field that takes string input. ASP.Net Core already checks  if it is empty or not because it is required.

[image]

I have put max and min length attributes on the module and when the input is not valid I want to change this message.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is really simple. All I had to do was add this attribute to the model property

`[StringLength(8, ErrorMessage = "{0} length must be between {2} and {1}.", MinimumLength = 6)]`

Where the first parameter is the maximum length and the last parameter is the minimum length

More information about this model validation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#error-messages)

Answer (score 1):

For complex validation requirements, you can check out **FluentValiation**. It is a great tool to help make your validation easy to create and easy to maintain.

https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html